# Eclipse 2020-09-R won't launch - even though I have jdk 11.0.8 installed

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently installed Eclipse 2020-09-R.   If I try to launch, it displays the following error:

[image]

Thing is - I have jdk 11.0.8 installed, and I even have my JAVA_HOME set to the jdk-11.0.8 folder.  Further if I do a 'java -version' it says I am running java version "11.0.8"

It is true I also have jdk1.8.0_281 installed, which I need to run another app.

Also, I can make Eclipse 2020-09-R launch if I re-name my jdk1.8.0_281 to something like jdk1.8.0_281xx - but I'm pretty sure that's not how it's supposed to work.

I can't find anywhere in my eclipse.ini file or anywhere else where jdk1.8.0_281 is hard-coded.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

My eclipse.ini file..

[image]

Comment: Why are you installing an old Eclipse? The curent version is 2021-03 which comes with a built in Java.

Comment: Is it a 64-bit Java 11?

Comment: It is in fact a 64-bit java 11 - 11.0.8 to be exact.

Comment: You have `-vm {path}` on one line. As (other) David's answer said, it must be on **two lines** in the ini file (although if you put it on the _shortcut_ that has `exe -vm path -vmargs stuff` all on one line).

Comment: I've tried it on one line in the ini file; on two lines in the ini file, and pretty much every other way possible.  I've tried reinstalling java 11; I've tried reinstalling WL with java 11 as I thought maybe it was because I originally installed it using java 1.8 Thanks for all the suggestions, but it's obsessed with thinking it's still on 1.8_281.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eclipse.ini is exactly where you specify what VM to run Eclipse with.  You specify the path to the VM to use with an option like this:

```
-vm
<Path to "bin" directory of JDK>
```

This should be before any "-vmargs" line.

Comment: Thanks - I do appreciate it.  I had already tried that earlier; no avail.  I tried it again (I added a shot of my eclipse.ini file to the original question).

I also tried it:

-vm C:/jdk-11.0.8/bin/

-vm C:\jdk-11.0.8\bin

-vm C:\jdk-11.0.8\bin\javaw.exe

-vm
C:\Java\jdk-11.0.8\1.8\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: I've even tried putting other jdk versions - it still complains about the 1.8.0_281.  Eclipse 2020-09 is recommended for the app.  I probably will try another version but I wish I knew why it's so obsessed with thinking I'm specifying 1.8.0_281,

Comment: This is the point where I would fire up sysinternals process monitor and see what is actually being refenced.

Answer (score 0):

Re-installation of the eclipse solved the problem for me. I tried all the solutions available on the web and did some modification in eclipse.ini as well. but none of the methods worked. Try it.